# Including custom code to astronomer airflow

Tags: airflow

I'm using astronomer's airflow solution, and I'm trying to add my own custom code from another repository.

My dag:

```py
from my_code.my_file import *

@dag(...)
def dag():
  pass
```

I have an ops pipeline that basically copies `my_code` into the `include` directory in the airflow setup (see the [quickstart guide](https://www.astronomer.io/docs/cloud/stable/get-started/quickstart#step-5-initialize-an-airflow-project) for more info).

Unfortunately, the dag import is failing with

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_code'

This is what the include directory looks like after the ops script copies the code:

```
.
├── include
│   └── my_code 
│       └── my_file.py
```

Any ideas or links to documentation about how to include custom code here?

---

### Edit:

Two more points to consider:

1. The business logic code needs to remain agnostic of the orchestration layer
2. The IDE shouldn't index the `include` directory, as it will contain duplicate code (it's a monorepo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `from include.my_code.my_file import *`.

**EDIT**

Or you could try to add the `include` folder to PYTHONPATH in the Dockerfile that is provided with Astronomer like: `ENV PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/local/airflow/include"`.

Comment: There are two problems with this: it requires you to change all the import statements recursively (if you have multiple business logic files) and the IDE fails to index the code, as `include` should not be an indexed directory (since it's all copied code)

Comment: @JoeyBaruch Might be worth updating the question a little with that context. Using a project created with the Astronomer CLI, that import statement worked but it seems like there is "more than meets the eye" with your use case.  I updated my answer to hopefully address your comment.